# Ruby enumerable method example

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

TL;DR: I'm new to Ruby and need help with Enumerable methods and how to use them.

I'm building an array of arrays of test information structured like so:

```
[[ "Run #", "Server", "Test", "OS", "Browser", "Result" ],
 [ "1", "bibble", "perf_test", "Windows 8", "firefox 33", "failed"]]
```

I'm trying to write a rudimentary stats output (sorted by result and other aspects, specifically so that it's immediately human-obvious whether, say, all the firefox tests are failing, or all the tests on server bibble are failing.) From what I can grasp, Enumerable operations will allow me to do this, but I cannot find clear examples (like, LI5 clear) examples of how to use the methods.

So my question is -- what is the simplest example possible of using Enumerable methods over at least a 3x3 array of arrays?

Comment: Could you give an example of the type of output you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking to get (roughly) counts for fail and success for each aspect of the tests, like 50% of the Firefox tests failed, etc.

I believe Mark Thomas' answer is what I needed, though. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a different data structure than an array of arrays. You can use a struct, a custom class, or even simply an array of hashes. This gives you a huge readability and queryability advantage and also a slight performance gain.

Here's an example of an array of hashes:

```
  runs =
    [{"Run #"  =>"1",
      "Server" =>"bibble",
      "Test"   =>"perf_test",
      "OS"     =>"Windows 8",
      "Browser"=>"firefox 33",
      "Result" =>"failed"
     },
     {"Run #"  =>2,
      "Server" =>"bibble",
      "Test"   =>"perf_test",
      "OS"     =>"Linux",
      "Browser"=>"firefox 26",
      "Result" =>"failed"
     }]
```

By the way, I created it from your array-of-arrays like so: `a.drop(1).map {|x| a.first.zip(x).to_h}`

Once you have it, you can query using the Enumerable method `select`. To find all failed firefox tests:

```
runs.select{|r| r["Result"]=="failed"}.select{|r| r["Browser"]=~/firefox/}
```

Comment: The code I'm writing is generating a fresh AoA every time I run it, so I can modify it to AoH (although I appreciate the map suggestion).

That example is the clearest one I've seen, and I'll work from it. Thank you!